# How can I extend the default Laravel 5 auth class to provide an admin interface which can delete and update users?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm building an admin interface that includes all elements of the application. I want to include a section that allows the administrator to edit user attributes and delete users.

Using the built-in User model and auth middlewares, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the Gate facade?

First create a ManageUsersPolicy class

```
class ManageUsersPolicy {
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function authorize(User $user) {
        // Whatever logic you want to authorize the current user, por example:
        return $user->hasRole('Admin');
    }
}
```

Then register the policy in your `AuthServiceProvider` class

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate) {
    $gate->define('manage-users', 'App\Policies\ManageUsersPolicy@authorize');
}
```

Then in your controller you can call:

```
if(Gate::denies('manage-users') {
    abort(403, 'You are nor authorized.');
} else {
    // This user is authorized to manage other users.
}
```

Checkout the documentation on policies:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization#policies